# Why does my browser say "uncaught referenceerror" here?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm just doing some tests in my browser to figure out what's going on - everything seems to be working correctly up until this line:

responseJson = JSON.parse(localReq.responseText);

When I evaluate this part:  JSON.parse(localReq.responseText);   I get the appropriate value. But when I evaluate "responseJson" it gives me an uncaught referenceerror and I can't figure out why.

```
function login()
{
   userName = document.getElementById("_name").value;
   password = document.getElementById("_password").value;
   data = "userName=" + userName + "&" + "password=" + password;
   localReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

   localReq.open("POST", "http://universe.tc.uvu.edu/cs2550/assignments/PasswordCheck/check.php", true);
   localReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   localReq.send(data);
   response = document.getElementById("_login");

   if (localReq.status == 200)
   {
      responseJson = JSON.parse(localReq.responseText);
   }



}
```

Comment: @torazaburo I have tried that.. about 100 different ways.. can you be more specific? Every other variable is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an event listener on your AJAX request to handle the response from the server asynchronously via a callback. By not doing this you are checking for a response code of `200` before the server has responded.

```
function login(){
   userName = "username";
   password = "password";
   data = "userName=" + userName + "&" + "password=" + password;
   localReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // use an event handler here
    localReq.addEventListener("load", function(evt){
        if (localReq.status == 200) {
            responseJson = JSON.parse(localReq.responseText);
            alert("Success: " + localReq.responseText);
        } else {
            alert("Not Success!= :(");
            console.log(localReq);
        }
    });

    localReq.open("POST", "http://universe.tc.uvu.edu/cs2550/assignments/PasswordCheck/check.php", true);
    localReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    localReq.send(data);
}
```

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wwsj3r4q/

Comment: Thank you! Obviously this is my first time.

Comment: No worries. Here is a good guide for using XmlHttpRequest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest